# Custom plugin issue - Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

Tags: plugins, custom-field, woocommerce-offtopic

In my plugin to configure some basic values using a woocommerce function which is creating a select field, but for some reason it generate this error:
"Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/wc-meta-box-functions.php on line 192"

It works but the error message on the screen driving me crazy. I can change value and save and everything is perfectly fine except the message.

```
function spinna360_nof($noi) {

woocommerce_wp_select( 
    array(
        'id'        => '_select_noi',
        'label'     => __( 'Select number of images: ', 'spinna360' ),
        'selected'  => true,
        'value'     =>  $noi,
        'options'   => [
            '24'        => __( '24', 'spinna360' ),
            '36'        => __( '36', 'spinna360' ),
            '48'        => __( '48', 'spinna360' )
            ]
        )
    );
}
```

Why?
What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>try use `global $post;` at the beginning of your function</strike>

Note that you've to run on a specific hook in order to work. see this post: https://www.ibenic.com/how-to-add-woocommerce-custom-product-fields/

```
function spinna360_nof() {
$noy=array(
    'id'        => '_select_noi',
    'label'     => __( 'Select number of images: ', 'spinna360' ),
    'selected'  => true,
    'options'   => [
        '24'        => __( '24', 'spinna360' ),
        '36'        => __( '36', 'spinna360' ),
        '48'        => __( '48', 'spinna360' )
        ]
);
woocommerce_wp_select($noy);   
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_data_panels', 'spinna360_nof');
```

Comment: Hi Andrea, I tried, does not help much :P

Comment: on which hook are you runing it?

Comment: Extend question a little bit please. Don't know  what you asking me for :)

Comment: I've updated my answer above

Comment: add_action( 'woocommerce_product_data_panels', 'spinna360_nof')

Comment: check my latest update, it should work now..

Comment: Either I'm doing something wrong .... or it just don't work :P

Comment: I think I got it, trying to add element into the custom (config) page with some random hooks while I should define custom hook then add action to it, or ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83172/discussion-between-andrea-somovigo-and-rob-d-a).